# How to register an install directory in the cmake package registry

Tags: cmake

Assume I have written a library `<mylib>` that I can build an install via cmake. And I also have a `<mylib>Config.cmake` file that can locate all necessary files (library, headers, ...) and exports a target for the library.

If I want to use the library with `find_package(...)`, cmake needs to know the location of the config file. I know that I could pass this every time I build a project using the library or I could (for cmake 3.13 and newer) point the `<mylib>_ROOT` environment variable to it.

But there is a solution for this that seems much simpler to me: I can register a package in the cmake package registry with the `export(PACKAGE <PackageName>)` command. But if I understand its [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/export.html) correctly this only allows to register the build directory. My build directories typically contain neither the config file, nor other stuff like include files that might be needed. Sure, I could copy them there, but why would I do this if I already have everything nicely set up in the install directory.

Therefore my questions:

- What is the reason that only registering of the build directory is supported by `export(PACKAGE ...)`?
- Is there any way to register my install directory in the cmake package registry?

Answer (score 1):

The use of the CMake package registry is discouraged because it is liable to change the behavior of other builds on the system. From the [latest documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/export.html) (emphasis mine):

> *Changed in version 3.15:* By default the `export(PACKAGE)` command **does nothing** (see policy [`CMP0090`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0090.html#policy:CMP0090)) because populating the user package registry has effects outside the source and build trees. Set the [`CMAKE_EXPORT_PACKAGE_REGISTRY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_PACKAGE_REGISTRY.html) variable to add build directories to the CMake user package registry.

To the extent that this question is an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), a better workflow is simply to pick a common install prefix, say `/path/to/prefix`, and then point every build that needs the packages in there to it via `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/prefix`. Build each project in dependency order and then `cmake --install /path/to/build --prefix /path/to/prefix` before moving on to the next.

This relieves you from setting `_ROOT` variables for each of your dependencies, because you have installed them all to the same prefix. `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is also one of the few environment variables that CMake reads to initialize the corresponding CMake variable, so you can set it in your shell to avoid typing `-D...` manually. To avoid affecting other projects on your system, something like [direnv](https://direnv.net/) might be useful to manage setting and unsetting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.